# kill -s SIGINT ps SHELL

Tags: shell

I am using this command kill -s SIGINT ps on the command line and it works (the process is eliminated), but when I use that command on a SHELL script it doesn´t work and it shows this error message kill: SIGNIT: invalid signal specification. How can I solve this. Thanks

Comment: @Wug: What you send to the process when your computer has lice.

Comment: inb4 someone makes a pun about lice and bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Error messages exist to give developers, and also users, a clue when something goes wrong.  I suspect that you're mistyping `SIGINT` as `SIGNIT`. The error message you're getting is consistent with a typo in your statement.

I feel like this shows poor research effort because if you had read the error message before asking help, you would have figured it out.

Comment: Doh!  I didn't even notice that discrepancy!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer this because I solved the similar problem recently. When you call `kill -s SIGINT`, you may use `sh` to run the script. Unfortunately, `sh` which is different from `bash`([linux shell kill signal SIGKILL && KILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423732/linux-shell-kill-signal-sigkill-kill)) will run in [compatibility mode](http://www.redhat.com/archives/nahant-list/2006-October/msg00138.html) and not recognize SIGINT.

The best solution is to use `/bin/bash` explicitly. By the way, `#!/bin/bash` doesn't work when you `sh` the script, either.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the shell executing the script is using a built-in "kill" command while your command-line shell is using an external binary, or vice-versa.  Use `/bin/kill` explicitly and see if that helps be more consistent.  `kill -SIGINT` is, I believe, the more common way of doing this (instead of "-s SIGINT").

Also, `kill` normally takes a process-id and not a process-name.  Built-in vs external "kill" commands may also support (or not support) this differently.

Comment: In a CentOS service init.d script I found only `kill -2` worked