# linux shell kill signal SIGKILL && KILL

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill

I just written a shell script to control the start and stop of a module. Everything seems normal until I find the stop command result in something unexpected.

I use the command `kill -s SIGKILL -- -gpid` to kill a group of processes. I use the `/bin/sh` to run the command like this

```sh
/bin/sh -c "kill -s SIGKILL -- -gpid"
```

which replied the error

```
/bin/sh: line 0: kill: SIGKILL: invalid signal specification
```

Then I replaced the `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash`, so the command is

```sh
/bin/bash -c "kill -s SIGKILL -- -gpid"
```

which replied nothing error. so I conclude the explanation that the difference between bash and sh cause the result. However, when I `ls` the `/bin/sh`, I found the `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`, so the command should be the same.

I found the command syntax `kill -s SIGKILL` is not in the syntax recommended, `kill -s KILL` recommended.

so I replaced the SIGKILL with KILL, the command is

```sh
/bin/sh -c "kill -s KILL -- -gpid"
```

which replied nothing error. as described above, anyone could explained this case.

Comment: What is your distribution? On my Ubuntu 12.04, `/bin/sh` actually points to `/bin/dash`. Could it be that in yours it's also `dash` and you read `bash`?

Comment: When `bash` is invoked as `sh` (e.g. via symlink, as in your case), it uses a sh compatibility mode where most modern features are turned off. I'd bet `sh` is calling the external binary for `kill`, and it doesn't recognize `SIGKILL`, but the `bash` invocation is using its builtin, and that builtin does.

Comment: @Kevin, does bash do that by checking its `argv[0]`?

Comment: @Kevin you should suggest that as an answer

Comment: You should NOT use SIGKILL (-9). Use SIGTERM (-15) or SIGINT or SIGHUP. When you using SIGKILL the program can't correctly shutdown itself, can't remove temporary files, can't close sockets nor send signal to its childrens...

Comment: @Shahbaz yes, it checks `argv[0]`.

Comment: @jm666 yeah, the differences between the threee signals really exists.However, I don't want the signal to be ignored and the module stopped as soon as it received the signal, which makes the SIGKILl the best choice. Thank you for your suggestions, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The only *truly* portable way to write this command is

```
kill -9 -$gpid
```

*None* of the ways to specify a signal *name* rather than a signal number work on the Unixes that froze their shell utilities in the mid-90s, which is basically all of them except Linux and the open-source BSDs.  However, SIGKILL is reliably signal number 9 and has always been so (since V7 if not earlier).

The special argument `--` isn't portable either, and is unnecessary in this case.

If you want to be a little more polite about it (sending SIGTERM instead) then use

```
kill -15 -$gpid
```

Again, that number is reliable all the way back to V7.

Answer (score 3):

When bash is invoked as `sh` (e.g. via symlink, as in your case), it uses a `sh` compatibility mode where most modern features are turned off. I'd bet `sh` is calling the external binary for `kill`, and it doesn't recognize `SIGKILL`, but the bash invocation is using its builtin, and that builtin does.

Comment: Sounds great.Is there any way to check the difference between the external kill and the built kill or some way to trace the progress of the execution of the command I mentioned.

Comment: I find it doesn't work as described above, for you can disable the built-in kill with the command 'enable -n kill and then execute the 'kill -s SIGKILL pid' that also works. So I guess there must be something not mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about [bash compatibility](http://www.redhat.com/archives/nahant-list/2006-October/msg00138.html). Quick fix to use `/bin/bash` because `sh` can't recognize SIGINT or other features.