# Docker compose stop depending service when done

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose.yml which runs a node script which depends on Redis.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis:/data
  node:
    image: "node:17-alpine"
    user: "node"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - REDIS_HOST_ENV=redis
    volumes:
      - ./docker/node/src:/home/node/app
      - ./docker/node/log:/home/node/log
    expose:
      - "8081"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    command: "npm start"
```

When starting this script with `docker compose up` both services will start. However when the `node` service is finished, the `redis` service keeps running. Is there a way to define that the `redis` service can stop when the node service is done?

Comment: [How to stop all containers when one container stops with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799885/how-to-stop-all-containers-when-one-container-stops-with-docker-compose) suggests `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`, though that requires you to run the containers in the foreground and might not scale to larger applications.  Is that enough for your needs?

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have examined the documentation for [Compose Spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) but I have not found anything that allows you to immediately stop containers based on the state of another one. Perhaps there really is a way, but you can always control the behaviour of the redis service by using an healthcheck:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ping -c 2 mynode || kill 1
      interval: 5s
      retries: 1
      start_period: 20s
  node:
    image: "node:17-alpine"
    container_name: mynode
    user: "node"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - REDIS_HOST_ENV=redis
    volumes:
      - ./docker/node/src:/home/node/app
      - ./docker/node/log:/home/node/log
    expose:
      - "8081"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    command: "npm start"
```

As for the `node` service, I have added a `container_name: mynode`, necessary by the `redis` service in order to contact it. The container name becomes also the hostname, if not specified with the `hostname` property.

The `redis` service has an `healthcheck` that ping the node container every 5 seconds, starting after 30 seconds from the container start. If the ping is successful, the container is labeled as *healthy*, otherwise it is `kill`ed.

This solution might work in your case but has some downsides:

- The healthcheck feature is abused here, besides what if you had another healthcheck?
- You cannot always kill the `init` process, because protected by default. There are some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538314/stopping-docker-container-from-inside) about this and it seems the most popular decision is to use `tini` as the init process. Fortunately, in the image you are using, it is possible.
- `redis` service contacts the `node` service via the hostname, which means that they are supposed to be in the same network in your case. The current network is the default bridge network that should be avoided most of the times. I suggest you to declare a custom bridge network.
- This solution is based on polling the `node` container, which is not very elegant, firstly because you have to hope that the time-based parameters in the `healthcheck` section are "good-enough".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Using healthcheck for this purpose feels a bit odd. The command `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` suggested in the comments looks like a better fitting solution

Comment: it is definitely odd but it is one of the only option you have as far as I know. `--abort-on-container-exit` does not let you to control the behaviour of every single service, but I am glad it is enough for you :)

Comment: Find this odd too but it's the best solution I found for now since for `--abort-on-container-exit` is not an option since some containers may end legitimely before others and I don't want to kill all at this time. I still have to made some changes since my service (that is `redis` here) must run with `tty: true` then `kill 1` doesn't work I then changed healthcheck test to kill every PIDs (this may be more that I need but I can't find who to kill) `test: ping -c 2 redis || kill $(ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v PID)`.